# Google maps geocoding issues

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, google-maps, geocoding

I'm having some issues with Google Maps Geocoding.

1. For some reason, the map works on here, but not on my website - I cannot understand why
2. If I don't include `address = encodeURI(address);`, I get an `INVALID_REQUEST` alert.
3. If I `alert` the address variable, I get `undefined`
4. If I run the code you can see below, it changes the maps location to somewhere in Kansas City.

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google_map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
  });
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  address = encodeURI(address);
  alert(address);
  
  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: resultsMap,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#google_map{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDxaUk0vMG2pm-ISIDrbi1PzKHBj5gzxVg&callback=initMap"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
           <input id="address" type="textbox" value="4 Chantry Road, Bishops Stortford, Hertfordshire, CM23">
           <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
         </div>
         <div id="google_map"></div>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to solve this was:

- Make sure to have service API enable (on Google API Dashboard)
- Generate a Javascript Credential for use with Javascript API
- Generate a Server Credential for use with Server API
- Configurate initializers for Geocode

HTML CODE

```
<input type="text" id="mapaddress" />
<input type="submit" id="change" onclick="changeMap()">


<div id="map" style="width: 413px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

JS :

```
function changeMap(){

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.00, -3.00),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  //var address = '3410 Taft Blvd  Wichita Falls, TX 76308';
  var address= document.getElementById("mapaddress").value;

  if(!address) {
    address = '3410 Taft Blvd  Wichita Falls, TX 76308';
  }

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  return false;
}
```

Comment: THANKS!!! I have no idea why the original code from google didn't work but yours does.

Comment: If or when you have the time could you put comments at the side of the code. For the code that accomplished your last three bullet points. Thanks

Comment: are you able to edit? please do that for me. I am not clear with your statement.